# laravel no instala carpeta vendor cuando creo un proyecto

Tags: laravel

estoy usando ubuntu 20.10 y he instalado composer de forma global estoy usando xampp al momento de querer crear un proyecto de laravel (8) me doy cuenta de que no me crea la carpeta vendor, ya vi videos y documentos en internet y a ninguno le da este problema.

al querer ejecutar php artisan serve me aparece el siguiente error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba/artisan on line 18
```

espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué versión de composer estas usando?

Comment: la version 2.x.x

Comment: ¿Con qué creas el proyecto laravel, con el instalador de laravel o con composer?

Answer (score 1):

Debes ejecutar `composer install` para que composer se encargue de cargar las dependencias necesarias, y obviamente la terminal se debe encontrar en la raíz de tu proyecto

Comment: tengo instalado composer de forma global, deberia funcionar en cualquier proyecto no? para no instalarlo en cada proyecto

Comment: Se refiere a que, dentro de tu proyecto creado de laravel, ejecutes `composer install` este sirve para instalar paquetes que no se hayan instalado anteriormente.

Comment: Composer solo es el gestor de dependencias, tenerlo de manera global solo significa que podrás ejecutar composer en cualquier directorio, para obtener las dependencias que requiere tu proyecto, necesitaas ejecutar `composer install` en cada uno de tus proyectos